# Fast, concise way to generate ordered frequency count of unique matrix rows

Tags: r

I have a matrix with some non-unique rows, e.g.:

```
x <- read.csv(textConnection(
'0,1,1,0
0,1,1,0
1,0,1,0
0,1,0,1
1,0,0,1'),
header = FALSE)
```

The challenge a quick way (a function called `umat_count` perhaps) to arrive at the count of the unique rows of this matrix, in the order that they appear in x. Ideally the result would look like:

```
y <- umat_count(x) 
y
##    2    1    1    1
```

To test this result is what I want, we can create unique version of x and then sample its rows y times and we get back to x:

```
ux <- unique(x)
ux[rep(1:nrow(ux), y),]

## V1 V2 V3 V4
## 1    0  1  1  0
## 1.1  0  1  1  0
## 3    1  0  1  0
## 4    0  1  0  1
## 5    1  0  0  1
```

So the question is what's a quick way to write `umat_count`? ATM this is the clunky code I have but I'm sure there's a better way, perhaps a one liner:

```
umat_count <- function(x) {
  xp <- apply(x, 1, paste0, collapse = "") # "pasted" version of constraints
  freq <- table(xp) # frequency of occurence of each individual
  xu <- unique(x) # save only unique individuals
  rns <- as.integer(row.names(xu)) # save the row names of unique values of ind
  xpu <- xp[rns]
  # xpu <- apply(xu, 1, paste0, collapse = "") # old way of generating ind_pu
  o <- order(xpu, decreasing = TRUE) # the order of the output (to rectify table)
  y <- freq[o] # frequency with which each individual appears (more efficient way?)
  y
}

y <- umat_count(x)
```

For context, I'm using this in the data preparation stage of an effort to optimise R scripts for 'spatial microsimulation' as described in this course-book: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ffnrl2ofv18rm3n/book-cambridge.pdf?dl=0

Many thanks.

Comment: If line 6 of your sample data were `0,1,1,0`, what would your desired result be?

Comment: @AnandaMahto This is a very good question. I would like the result to be `3 1 1 1`. But when I use the @blakeoft method, this fails: without sort I get `2 1 1 1 1 `. With sort the order is wrong: `1 3 1 1 `. This is a problem - any ideas?

Comment: I've created [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/b83017e62915586c8f99) with a "dplyr" and "data.table" function if you want to test them out to see what best suits your needs. The reason I've kept a new variable as a list of rownames is in case you really want to recreate exactly your original data from the compressed version of the data.

Comment: Thanks - your dplyr implementation seems overly verbose though. Will test different approaches on larger and more complex datasets.

Comment: "Overly verbose" would depend on what you expect to be able to do with the data later. Of course it could be condensed if just the counts in the right order is all that's required--but you aren't going to be able to use that information alone to be able to recreate your original dataset, which you indicate as part of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @AnandaMahto fair point - aggree speed/robustness are more important.

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer:

```
y <- apply(x, 1, paste, collapse = " ")
y <- rle(sort(as.numeric(factor(y, unique(y), ordered = T))))$lengths
```

Or the `do.call` way:

```
y <- do.call(paste, as.data.frame(x))
y <- rle(sort(as.numeric(factor(y, unique(y), ordered = T))))$lengths
```

---

Try

```
y <- rle(apply(x, 1, paste, collapse = " "))
# y$lengths is the vector containing the number of times each row appears
# y$values are the rows in the order that y$lengths reports frequency
```

Credit goes to @JonathanChang, see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572559/r-counting-the-occurrences-of-similar-rows-of-data-frame) this page for his solution. If the rows are out of order, you should sort them before using `rle`.

```
y <- rle(sort(apply(x, 1, paste, collapse = " ")))
```

Comment: Confirmed: `y <- rle(apply(x, 1, paste, collapse = ";"))[[1]]` is just what I'm after - brownie points for a 1 liner - never seen rle before and constantly amazed by what base R can do.

Comment: `do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(x))` might be faster than `apply` for bigger matrices.

Comment: I thought about `paste0`, but what if one row in the matrix is `c(11, 0)` and another is `c(1, 10)`? So I stuck with `paste` instead.

Comment: @blakeoft, the point is not so much the difference between `paste0` and `paste` as much as it is about the approach to combining the columns. It could just as easily be `do.call(paste, ...)`.

Comment: @blakeoft your answer no longer works! `rle(apply(x, 1, paste))
Error in rle(apply(x, 1, paste)) : 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type` Please update

Comment: @RobinLovelace I've updated my answer. I took away the collapse argument in a previous edit that broke my solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update - unfortunately the code does not work for the more general case, e.g. if line 6 is `0, 1, 0, 1` - should have created a more difficult version of `x` as the initial condition. Robin

Comment: @RobinLovelace If you add that sixth row, you'll want to sort the rows before using `rle`. Do you want the frequencies reported in order of first appearance of the rows?

Comment: @blakeoft yes I think what you say is precisely what I'm after. Please see the output of `umat_count(x)` on the updated `dplyr` implementation below. Thanks.

Comment: @RobinLovelace I know that there's a way to preserve the order of the rows with my answer. I'll work it out today when I get time.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the `do.call` hint. I don't think I knew exactly what it did.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider the "data.table" package, which you can use like this:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(x, keep.rownames = TRUE)[, list(n = .N, rn = rn[1]), by = names(x)]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 n rn
# 1:  0  1  1  0 2  1
# 2:  1  0  1  0 1  3
# 3:  0  1  0  1 1  4
# 4:  1  0  0  1 1  5
```

I've added the "rn" column to be able to make sure we maintain the row order later on if necessary.

---

If rows are mixed up, and one of your objectives is to try to recreate the original dataset, I would suggest creating a `list` of the row positions, something like this:

```
X <- as.data.table(x)  ## your new "x" in your answer
X[, rn := sequence(nrow(X))][, list(
    .N, rn = list(rn)), by = eval(paste0("V", 1:4))]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 N    rn
# 1:  0  1  1  0 3 1,2,6
# 2:  1  0  1  0 1     3
# 3:  0  1  0  1 1     4
# 4:  1  0  0  1 1     5
str(.Last.value)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ V1: int  0 1 0 1
#  $ V2: int  1 0 1 0
#  $ V3: int  1 1 0 0
#  $ V4: int  0 0 1 1
#  $ N : int  3 1 1 1
#  $ rn:List of 4
#   ..$ : int  1 2 6
#   ..$ : int 3
#   ..$ : int 4
#   ..$ : int 5
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Since you have a `list` in `rn`, you can later use `unlist` and `order` to get back to your original format.

Comment: I've marked this one as correct as it maintains the column order - should have stated that repeated rows can appear anywhere in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

For the record (sorry for answering my own question) here's another solution that makes use of [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr). Concise and gets the rows in the right order regardless of where repeated rows happen. Starting with x as a data.frame:

```
library(dplyr)


rns <-as.integer(row.names(unique(x)))
x$p <- apply(x, 1, paste0, collapse = "")
up <- p[rns]
y <- count(x, p)
o <- order(up, decreasing = TRUE)
y$n[o]
```

Test on dataset that the `rle` solution would fail on, (thanks to Anananda):

```
x <- read.csv(textConnection(
  '0,1,1,0
  0,1,1,0
  1,0,1,0
  0,1,0,1
  1,0,0,1
  0,1,0,1'),
  header = FALSE)

umat_count_dplyr <- function(x){
rns <-as.integer(row.names(unique(x)))
x$p <- apply(x, 1, paste0, collapse = "")
up <- p[rns]
y <- count(x, p)
o <- order(up, decreasing = TRUE)
y$n[o]} # correct order of output
umat_count(x)

  V1 V2 V3 V4    p ind_num rns
1  0  1  1  0 0110       2   1
3  1  0  1  0 1010       1   3
4  0  1  0  1 0101       2   4
5  1  0  0  1 1001       1   5
```

The problem: this solution is just as long and slower than my original `umat_count` function - perhaps the dplyr solution will be relatively faster with bigger datasets. Hopefully there are better ways of writing this overall...

```
microbenchmark(umat_count(x), umat_count_dplyr(x))
Unit: microseconds
                expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
       umat_count(x)  698.606  714.710  770.613  742.501  770.3165 3061.149   100
 umat_count_dplyr(x) 1142.678 1168.565 1249.977 1187.452 1214.5750 3579.286   100
```

Comment: Where's the `count` function from?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/358 you may need to `install_github("hadley/dplyr")`. Robin

Comment: Ok. I'll update to this version and see what other changes have been implemented. It might be that my `regroup` line can now be rewritten.

Comment: Good stuff - let me know how you progress. I couldn't make dplyr provide the output in the right order, hence the extra lines of code.

Comment: I mentioned this in the comments of my own answer, but I just want to bring it back up here. Be careful with `collapse = ""`. I don't know what your data looks like, but `collapse = ""` will break if you have the rows `c(11, 0)` and `c(1, 10)`. They'll both be `"110"` after pasting.